# Rails - how to get absolute url of an asset in css.erb

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get the absolute url of an image in my css as follows:

```
"#{request.scheme}://#{request.host_with_port}/assets/image.png);"
```

But I think request attributes cannot be accessed in css.erb. Can anyone tell me how else can I get the request scheme and host_with_port attributes in my css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define "scheme" (more correct: protocol), host and port by defining asset_host in your  application configuration, though this definition will be used for all your asset paths.

Refering to the Rails API documentation on [Asset Tag Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) request informations can be used:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
      "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
}
```

If you need different values for different types of assets, you can define filter criteria, e.g.:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
 if source.starts_with?('/images')
   "http://images.example.com"
 else
   "http://assets.example.com"
 end
}
```

Comment: Tried it by putting it inside environments/development.rb but couldn't get it working.

Comment: try this in your environments/development.rb: `config.action_controller.asset_host...`

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm accepting it as it solves the question asked. Urls were replaced properly, but unfortunately it didn't help solve my problem which I have raised in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208403/rails-imgkit-issues-in-exporting-images-with-html-and-css

Answer (score 0):

You can define css with absolute url for any background image or other assets. So you can generate it dynamically following this [How to get absolute image paths in your css files using sass/scss](https://coderwall.com/p/exj0ig).

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-image: image-url(background.png);
}
```

In your environment file change it with yours

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://your.domain.com/"
```

Then your css will look something like that:

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://your.domain.com/assets/background.png);
}
```