# (Rails) IMGKIT - Issues in exporting images with html and css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imgkit

I'm using IMGKIT in one of my projects and had to use their css with html option to satisfy a requirment. I noticed that if stylesheets are set as follows:

```
kit = IMGKit.new(html, :quality => 50)
kit.stylesheets << '/path/to/css/file'
```

and the stylesheet has a background property with a relative url('image.png'), image is not generated when exporting it using kit.to_file:

```
(Rails.root + "public/pngs/" + "image.png")
```

The request hangs, and if we replace the background url to full url with protocol, host and port, it is well exported.

Do I need to have absolute urls to all my images in my stylesheet?

I have tried defining asset_host in my development.rb file:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
     "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
    }
```

It does replace the url in the css if I check on browser but still the images are not generated when exported through IMGKIT.

Answer (score 5):

IMGKIT reqiured css with absolute url for any background image or other assets.
So you can generate it dynamically following this link https://coderwall.com/p/exj0ig and some steps as

**A)** Put your all images in assets/images folder of rails app

**B)** Install gem 'sass-rails' if not install https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

**C)** create another css file name as css_file_name.css.sccs.erb

**D)** put your all other css file content in it.

**E)** In css file just put your image file name as below:
background-image: image-url('image.png');

**F)** Use assets pipline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline)
Run below command as your app mode: 
(1) Development Mode: RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
(2) Production Mode: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

**G)** In your config/environments/

(1) In development.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "YOUR LOCAL HOST URL i.e YOUR_LOCALHOST_ADDRESS"

(2) In production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com" /*YOUR ADDRESS*/

**H)** And last relate your stylesheet with IMGKIT as below

```
html_content = "YOUR HTML CONTENT"
kit = IMGKit.new(html_content, height: 900, transparent:true, quality:10) /*YOUR SETTING*/
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/application.css"
file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/pngs/" + "screenshot.png") /*YOUR IMAGE NAME*/
send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/pngs/screenshot.png", :filename => "screenshot.png", :type => "image/png",:disposition => 'attachment',:streaming=> 'true') /*YOUR ADDRESS WHERE U WANT TO STORE PNG FILE*/
```

**I)** Restart server and enjoy!!!!!

[**NOTE:** After every changes please run assets pipline command to get latest application.css which is made from .sccs.erb extension file.]

Comment: what about the rails 4 because there will be a fingerprint with application.css how will you give that path.For more info plz see my SO question regarding same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736713/how-to-give-fingerprint-css-path-in-production-rails-4