# Using scss in IMGKIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, imgkit

I would like to use scss for imgkit, but imgkit only takes in css. I thought of rendering the scss as a string, but i am not sure how to pass it into imgkit.

```
kit = IMGKit.new(get_card_html, :quality => 70, :width=> 200, :height=> 324)

// IMGKit normally takes in a file path
kit.stylesheets << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets','stylesheets' ,'cards.css').to_s

// rendered it to string. how do i pass it into imgkit?
Onethingaday::Application.assets.find_asset('cards.css').body
```

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208403/rails-imgkit-issues-in-exporting-images-with-html-and-css