# How to give fingerprint css path in production rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, precompile, imgkit

I am using `imgkit` to take snapshot of my webpage. I run:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` To precompile my assets.

All file of `app/assets` directory are compiled to `public/assets`
`application.css` compiled as `application-7a23a105125768e41d9d24aee4553615.css`.

My controller code is:

```
  kit = IMGKit.new(render_to_string(:partial => 'form', :height => 200, :transparent => true, :quality => 10, :layout => false,:locals => {:project => @project}))
  #  t = kit.to_img(:png) 
  kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/assets/application.css"
  #file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/pngs/" + "screenshot.png")
  file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/assets/" + "screenshot.png")
  #send_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/pngs/screenshot.png", :filename => "screenshot.png", :type => "image/png",:disposition => 'attachment',:streaming=> 'true')
```

I don't know how to resolve `/public/assets/application.css` not found error...

No such file or directory - public/assets/application.css

I am using https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit/issues/36 to get css and work in my snapshot

**edits**

```
def update
#@kit = IMGKit.new(render_to_string, width: 480, height: 800, :quality => 100)
  respond_to do |format|
   if @project.update(project_params)
    kit = IMGKit.new(render_to_string(:partial => 'form', :height => 200, :transparent => true, :quality => 10, :layout => false,:locals => {:project => @project}))
  #  t = kit.to_img(:png) 
  kit.stylesheets << "self.class.helpers.asset_path('application.css')"
    #file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/pngs/" + "screenshot.png")
 file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/assets/" + "screenshot.png")
 #send_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/pngs/screenshot.png", :filename => "screenshot.png", :type => "image/png",:disposition => 'attachment',:streaming=> 'true')
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Flyer was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, locatioFlyern: @project }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: why you precompile on development environment? it will not take any effect in development, you should do that only on production.

Comment: As mentioned https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit/issues/36   i precompiled it!!

Comment: Can any one help me to overcome from this

Comment: `application-7a23a105125768e41d9d24aee4553615.css` is not the same as `application.css`. Thus it can not be found.

Comment: @scones that i know but how can i give fingerprint path in production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Sprockets::Rails::Helper#asset_digest_path`, found [here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb#L108). Since you are in the controller, you have access to it with

```
self.class.helpers.asset_digest_path('application.css')
# => "application-7a23a105125768e41d9d24aee4553615.css"
```

Similarly, `asset_path` will yield the path to the application.css file

```
self.class.helpers.asset_path('application.css')
# => "/assets/application-7a23a105125768e41d9d24aee4553615.css"
```

Comment: it gives ERROR 'No such file or directory !!'bad luck

Comment: What if you do it in production mode? `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` and then `RAILS_ENV=production rails console` and in there, `ApplicationController.helpers.asset_path('application.css')`? Do you have an `application.css` file in your public/assets folder after compiling your assets?

Comment: application-7a23a105125768e41d9d24aee4553615.css file created instead of application.css as i am using rails 4

Comment: plz see my projects controller in Edited post!!

Comment: If `"#{Rails.root}/public/assets/#{self.class.helpers.asset_digest_path('application.css')}"` gives you the correct path to your css file, then you should add `kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/#{self.class.helpers.asset_digest_path('application.css')}"`. The reason why just `"self.class.helpers.asset_digest_path('application.css')"` doesn't work is because at that point it is simply a string, not the path to your `application.css` file.

Comment: let me try ones again!!

Comment: Now problem is in this line   file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/assets/" + "screenshot.png")http://localhost:3000/assets/screenshot.png No such file or directory

Comment: This is beyond the scope of your original question, but `Rails.root + "public/assets/" + "screenshot.png"` should translate to something along the lines of `/path/to/rails/public/assets/screenshot.png`, not `localhost:3000/assets/screenshot.png` so I don't think that particular line is the issue.

Comment: I am using Rails 4.2.6 and in my controller `self.class.helpers.asset_digest_path('application.css')` is returning nothing and `self.class.helpers.asset_path('application.css')` is returning `/application.css` and not the finger-printed file name lying under `/public/assets` folder which I generated using `rake assets:precompile`. I am working on a feature involving ImgKit and want to include my CSS and JS in context of development environment. How can I make this work?

Comment: @AnishShah can you please let me know how you resolved your issue of using the pre-compiled asset path in ImgKit?